# How can I pass the value from Action Method to Action Filter which is contained in Model not in Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

The scenario is like that I have an Index action method which is downloading a file and after downloading gets over I need to delete that file from my application. 
To delete the file I have created an action filter `OnActionExecuted` which is contained in Model. Now the problem is that I don't know how can I access the filename inside this action filter? 
This is action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [DeleteFile]
    public virtual ActionResult Index(TranscriptViewModel model)
    {
        string exportedFileName = model.GetFileName();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exportedFileName))
        {
            var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(@"App_Data\" + exportedFileName));
            return File(fileStream, "application/" + model.Format.ToLower(), model.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            model.IsShowErrorMsg = true;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

`exportedFileName`  is the file name which I need to access in the below action filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string fileName = "I need file name here";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me the way how can I achieve this requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how the file name was builded? I mean this method: model.GetFileName();

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code in your controller action, that will achieve the desired result for you:

```
string exportedFileName = model.GetFileName();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exportedFileName))
{
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";//change as needed
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + exportedFileName);
context.Response.TransmitFile(context.Server.MapPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(setupDirectory, setupName)));
// Add redirect here if you like
context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
context.HttpContext.Response.End();
System.IO.File.Delete(exportedFileName);
}
else
{
model.IsShowErrorMsg = true;
return View(model);
}
```